# Spring validation fix

Tags: java, spring

I have validator validating, for instance, input data. It gets object `product` (class `Product`) created with default `constructor`. One of Product fields is `description`, and it has `@NotNull` annotation.

When I run test it fails obviously and shows `NullPointerException`. I can surround part of code where `NullPointerException` was thrown with if-else like this

```
if(description!=null){
 // product validation
}else{
  errors.rejectValue("description", errorCode, defaultMessage);
}
```

That works, but i need something else, maybe using annotations.

Comment: how are you running the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You con use something like [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) to create a mock of the [`BindingResult`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html) that has a method [`hasErrors()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#hasErrors%28%29) to check for any errors.

[See more solutions...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877423/mocking-spring-mvc-bindingresult-when-using-annotations)