# How to mock BindingResult in Spring Boot Test

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I have the following controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = ROOT_MAPPING)
public class GatewayController {

    @Autowired
    private RequestValidator requestValidator;

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(requestValidator);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = REDIRECT_MAPPING)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> redirectEndpoint(@Validated @RequestBody RequestDTO requestDTO, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            // Handle validation errors
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }

        // Do other stuff
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }
}
```

And this test class:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(GatewayController.class)
public class GatewayControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private RequestValidator requestValidator;

    @MockBean
    private BindingResult bindingResult;

    private JacksonTester<RequestDTO> requestJacksonTester;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        JacksonTester.initFields(this, new ObjectMapper());
        Mockito.when(requestValidator.supports(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenRedirectWithValidationErrorsThenBadRequestReturned() throws Exception {
        RequestDTO request = new RequestDTO();
        // Set some values

        Mockito.when(bindingResult.hasErrors()).thenReturn(true);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(ROOT_MAPPING + REDIRECT_MAPPING)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(requestJacksonTester.write(request).getJson()))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

When I run this code the test case fail with this reason: Status
Expected :400
Actual   :200

So, what I want to do is to mock the `BindingResult` which passed as a parameter to the `redirectEndpoint` method in the Controller so that when calling `bindingResult.hasErrors()` this should return true and the test case pass.

I did many search but with no luck. Any suggestions how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BindingResult` is not a *bean* in the `ApplicationContext`. Thus, you cannot *mock* it via `@MockBean`.

A `BindingResult` is created for you by Spring MVC for each incoming HTTP request.

Thus, you don't want to mock the `BindingResult`. In fact, you probably don't want to mock the behavior of your `RequestValidator` either. Rather, you should ideally use the real implementation of your `RequestValidator`, pass in *invalid* request data (via `MockMvc`), and then verify the response accordingly.

Note that you should be able to *include* the real implementation of your `RequestValidator` via `@Import(RequestValidator.class)` on the test class.

Comment: Thank you so much @sam-brannen, this solved my problem. Yes, you are correct I should use the real implementation of `RequestValidator`. I removed `requestValidator` and  `bindingResult` then added `@Import(RequestValidator.class)` and everything worked fine.