# How to mock BindingResult in Spring Boot test?

Tags: spring-boot

In a TestClass I added  `@Import(MandatairesFormValidator.class)`
When I mock the controller I can go inside the controller but I can't access  the method validate.validate() as suggested here: [How to mock BindingResult in Spring Boot Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001043/how-to-mock-bindingresult-in-spring-boot-test)

The controller is:

```
 @PatchMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
  ResponseEntity<Object> modifierDonnees(@PathVariable final Long id,
    @Valid @RequestBody final ModificationUI modificationUI, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        validator.validate(modificationUI, bindingResult);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            List<String> errors = bindingResult.getAllErrors().stream().map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage).collect(Collectors.toList());
            throw new MandataireValidationException(errors);
        }
}
```

The UnitTestController:

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ControllerTest {

```
ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(patch(URL_RACINE_CTRL + "/1").contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
        .content(
                "{\"modificationMandataire\":{\"mandataireOrigine\":{}, " +
                        "\"mandataireSoustraction1\":{}, " +
                        "\"mandataireSoustraction2\":{}}}")).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isBadRequest());
```

using: @Import(MandatairesFormValidator.class) the validator in the Controller is null ;
using:  @Mock
    private MandatairesFormValidator mandatairesFormValidator; it skips the 'validator.validate()' method -->
 BindingResult bindingResult = mock(BindingResult.class);
        when(bindingResult.hasErrors()).thenReturn(true);

The validator:

```
@Component
public class MandatairesFormValidator implements Validator {

    public static final String international_number="(0{1,2}|\\+\\d{2,})(-|\\.|\\s*|\\d*)*";


    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return ModificationUI.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    private Boolean isValidNatel(String telephone){
        return Objects.nonNull(telephone) && (telephone.matches(international_number));
    }

    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {

        ModificationUI modificationUI = (ModificationUI) o;
        ModificationMandataireUI modificationMandataire = modificationUI.getModificationMandataire();

        MandataireSoustractionUI mandataireSoustractionUI1 = modificationAffaireMandataire.getMandataireSoustraction1();
        MandataireSoustractionUI mandataireSoustractionUI2 = modificationAffaireMandataire.getMandataireSoustraction2();


        Boolean isValidNatel1 = (Objects.nonNull(mandataireSoustractionUI1) && isValidNatel(mandataireSoustractionUI1.getTelephone()) || Objects.isNull(mandataireSoustractionUI1));
        Boolean isValidNatel2 = (Objects.nonNull(mandataireSoustractionUI2)  && isValidNatel(mandataireSoustractionUI2.getTelephone()) || Objects.isNull(mandataireSoustractionUI2));


        if ( !isValidNatel1 ) {
            String telephone1=mandataireSoustractionUI1.getTelephone();
            String msg1= Objects.nonNull(telephone1) ? telephone1 : "";
            errors.reject("telephone", "Téléphone 1 " + msg1 +" pas valide");
        }
        if (  !isValidNatel2  ) {
            String telephone2=mandataireSoustractionUI2.getTelephone();
            String msg2= Objects.nonNull(telephone2) ? telephone2 : "";
            errors.reject("telephone", "Téléphone 2" + msg2 + " pas valide");
        }
    }
}`
```

I tried using

Comment: Ofcourse not if you mock the controller you are bypassing the implementation, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. What do you want to test (the controller or the validator) judging from  yur test you want to write an integration test for your controller (i.e. an `@WebMvcTest`).

Comment: Hi I want to test the controller. In order to test the validator I don't need any mock.When I test the controller I am not able to mock MandatairesFormValidator to pass inside validator.validate()

Comment: See chapter 8 of my book https://www.infoq.com/minibooks/spring-boot-building-api-backend/ on how to test validation.

Comment: Thanks Wi and my compliments for your book but  I can't still solve my problem.

Comment: Assuming you are using `@WebMvcTest` use `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock`.

Comment: Hi I don't use @WebMvcTest but @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)